# Change GlSurfaceView renderer

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview

I looked all over the net in order to find out if its possible to change the renderer of a GLSurfaceView on the flight. The reason is that I want to change the OpenGl program, and initiate all the attributes and unified params from its vertex and fragment shader and I don't want the any change would require to create a brand new GLSurfaceView with a brand new Renderer.

It seems like reasonable operation that should be doable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: I haven't implemented the following.

[`GLSurfaceView.Renderer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.Renderer.html) is an interface. Implement it three times. Twice for your different OpenGL renderers, and one time attached to the [`GLSurfaceView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html). The latter only dispatches to one of the former, and allows to change the renderer to which it dispatches. The code must hold a reference to this renderer, and eventually must be synchronized to the draw calls (though I don't know).

Be aware that you cannot easily switch OpenGLES context data. It is shared between all renderer instances.

```
class DispatchingRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    private class Renderer1 implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
       ...
    }
    private class Renderer2 implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
       ...
    }

    public DispatchingRenderer() {
        this.r1 = new Renderer1();
        this.r2 = new Renderer2();

        this.currentRenderer = this.r1;
    }
    public void ToggleRenderer() {
        if(this.currentRenderer == this.r1) {
            this.currentRenderer = this.r2;
        } else if (this.currentRenderer == this.r2) {
            this.currentRenderer = this.r1;
        }
    }
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        // do one-time setup
    }
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
        this.currentRenderer.onSurfaceChanged(gl, w, h);
    }
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        this.currentRenderer.onDrawFrame(gl);
    }
}
```