# How to 'exchange' the Renderer in a GLSurfaceView instance in android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

In android I have taken a rotating sphere example [given here](https://bitbucket.org/jimcornmell/opengltexturedsphere). It creates a simple app showing a rotating sphere (the earth).

Now, in a class derived from `GLSurfaceView` I wait for an even (like a touch-screen event) in order to exchange the renderer. I want the current renderer to stop rendering, and the `GLSurfaceView` should use a different renderer instead (to display some other object).

I have tried to use the following code:

```
public class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    Context mycontext;

    MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mycontext = context;
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();
        Log.d("onTouchEvent",String.format("keyCode: %d  coords: %d  %d", event.getActionMasked(), x, y));

        GlRenderer renderer = new GlRenderer(mycontext);
        setRenderer(renderer);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

which gives the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.jimscosmos.opengltexturedsphere, PID: 25708
java.lang.IllegalStateException: setRenderer has already been called for this instance.
```

I guess I have to stop/remove/destroy the 'old' renderer, but I did not find anything useful for that [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html). Maybe my approach is completely wrong? What else to do? How to do it right?

Comment: No, you shouldn't stop and change your renderer. Why don't you just exchange the object in the same renderer?

Comment: How to do so from within the `GLSurfaceView`?  Maybe you can reference an example?

Comment: No, change it from the renderer in the `onDrawFrame` function. Example: `if(something){ drawSphere1();}else{ drawSphere2();}`

Comment: Ah I see. I will try it and get back to you. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

If you insist, technically it can be achieved using a 'mediator' - as suggested here: [Change GlSurfaceView renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369099/change-glsurfaceview-renderer).

However - I think this is an overhead you really do not need. Simply prepare various objects and change the various rendering properties in a single renderer.

Comment: Can you provide some examples on how to do so?

Comment: I do not see the need - it depends on you specific implementation. Your renderer should be able to handle what ever task you want it to, and switch the tasks according to what you want (in the same condition you originally thought to change renderer)